# find contiguous stretches of equal data in a vector

Tags: r

I have a numeric vector, it contains patches of elements that are repeating, something like:

```
R> data <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,1,1,1,1,1)
R> data
 [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 1 1 1 1 1
R>
```

I need to extract contiguous patches of elements equals to a specific value...  but I'm only interested in the patch around a specific position.  so, my input is: (1) the numeric vector, (2) the desired value, (3) the position.  I want to return a logic vector indicating which positions satisfy the request.

if at that position the data does not equal the value, I return all `FALSE`.

possible outcomes that are not all `F` would be:

```
 [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 1 1 1 1 1

 [1] T T T F F F F F F F F F F F F F F F F F
 [2] F F F T T T F F F F F F F F F F F F F F
 [3] F F F F F F T T F F F F F F F F F F F F
 [4] F F F F F F F F T T T T T F F F F F F F
 [5] F F F F F F F F F F F F F T T F F F F F
 [6] F F F F F F F F F F F F F F F T T T T T
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502910/

Comment: I upvoted the comment because I found the link useful, but I don't think this is a duplicate question.  I'm still using my own solution in the code I'm distributing to my users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

writing questions here helps thinking about solutions...  and I found [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642783/) so I could come up with this one:

```
contiguousequal <- function(data, value, position) {
  if(data[position] != value)
    return(rep(FALSE, length(data)))
  id <- cumsum(c(1, as.numeric(diff(data) != 0)))
  id == id[position]
}
```